# MWE for beamerposter

Tags: beamerposter

I'm trying to strip down a beamerposter example so I can build my poster off of it. However, it's not compiling. Any idea why?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[size=custom,height=150,width=90,scale=1]{beamerposter}

\title{FOOBAR}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}

  \begin{columns}[t]

    \begin{column}[.45\linewidth]
      \begin{block}{FOOBAR}
        foobar
      \end{block}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{.45\linewidth}
      \begin{block}{FOOBAR}
       foobar
      \end{block}
    \end{column}

  \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm planning to do the same thing as you, however, the title is not appearing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first

```
\begin{column}[.45\linewidth]
```

should be

```
\begin{column}{.45\linewidth}
```

like the second